# UPDATING TABLE WITH SEQUENCE AND SUFFIX NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have below requirement in Oracle sql developer wherein I have one column which is PDF_SEQ_NUMBER and PDF_SUF_NUMBER, now for each pdf_id there should be a unique sequence number also when sequence value reaches 99 the PDF_SUF_NUMBER should reset to 02 and PDF_SEQ_NUMBER to 01. I need to update the table with these two columns PDF_SEQ_NUMBER and PDF_SUF_NUMBER. Please help me in this:

output coming as of now:

```
pdf_id      PDF_SUF_NUMBER   PDF_SEQ_NUMBER
1029117706  01                01
1029117706  01                01
1029117706  01                01
1030444073  01                02
1030444073  01                02
```

Expected output as below and here when PDF_SEQ_NUMBER changes to 99 then PDF_SUF_NUMBER needs to be 02 and PDF_SEQ_NUMBER needs to be 01:

```
pdf_id      PDF_SUF_NUMBER   PDF_SEQ_NUMBER
1029117706  01                01
1029117706  01                02
1029117706  01                03
1030444073  01                01
1030444073  01                02
```

Comment: It seems the table does not have a primary key (or any key for the matter). It won't be possible to update it consistently. I'll downvote the question for the time being, until you provide the PK.

Answer (score 0):

This should basically do want you want:

```
select t.*,
       to_char(floor(row_number() over (partition by pdf 
                                        order by pdf_suf_number, pdf_seq_number
                                       ) / 100
                    ), '00'
              ) as new_pdf_suf_number,
       to_char(mod(row_number() over (partition by pdf
                                      order by pdf_suf_number, pdf_seq_number
                                     ) - 1, 100
                  ), '00'
              ) as new_pdf_seq_number
from t;
```

The only difference is that it starts from `00` rather than `01`.  That makes more sense to me because it allows you to increment after 100 instead of 99.

You may find that the simplest approach is to just save the above (or rather the columns you want) into a new table, using `create table as`.  `UPDATE`s are slower than recreating the entire table.

You can update the values using:

```
update t
    set (pdf_suf_number, pdf_seq_number) =
          (select to_char(floor(row_number() over (partition by pdf order by pdf_suf_number, pdf_seq_number) / 100), '00') as new_pdf_suf_number,
                  to_char(mod(row_number() over (partition by pdf order by pdf_suf_number, pdf_seq_number) - 1, 100), '00') as new_pdf_seq_number
            from t t2
            where t2.rowid = t.rowid
           );
```

Comment: Thank you so much i will try this out and get back to you.

Comment: @dazzilingangel . . . Test the `select` first to be sure it does what you want.

Comment: select pdf_sfx_seq3.*,
       to_char(floor(row_number() over (partition by pdf_pid order by pdf_sfx_number, pdf_seq_number) / 100), , '00') as new_pdf_suf_number,
       to_char(mod(row_number() over (partition by pdf_pid order by pdf_sfx_number, pdf_seq_number) - 1, 100), '00') as new_pdf_seq_number
from pdf_sfx_seq3;

Comment: @GordonLinoff In the absence of a PK I don't think it's possible to update the table consistently.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  can you please tell how we can achieve same with the help of using MAX Function as I need to use Max function while updating table on pdf_seq_number column and when it reaches 99 i need to reset  PDF_SUF_NUMBER from 02 and pdf_seq_number  from 01.

Comment: @dazzilingangel . . . The `select` query should generate both values.  I see no role for a `max()` function, at least for this question.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.